# Simple app admin UI in Heroku or Firebase?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, firebase, react-native

I would appreciate if someone could point me to the more simple direction between Firebase and Heroku.

I'm planning a simple React Native photo app for scientific purposes (take image, save phone geolocation, send both details to database, that's it!).

I need to create a really simple admin UI for the submitted photos+geolocations: view, delete, tag photo (correct/incorrect), download geolocations. Just one user is OK.

Would it be easier me to create the admin UI on Firebase or Heroku? Or if there are already ready-made admin UI's available?

The stack is: React Native, Node.js (+ Express?), MongoDB

And, I'm not creating the app myself, but hiring a freelancer. Maybe they have their own preferences, but I was just interested to know of there's a big difference accessing the data in Firebase or Heroku.

Both the app and the admin UI shoudl be really simple, just bare-bones. I expect the app + admin ui to be created within 100 hrs.

Comment: So you want the admin UI in react native or in web/react?

Comment: Any simple browser-based admin UI is OK. It will be accessed via desktop.

Answer (score 0):

The core capability of Firebase is real time sync of data pushed to multiple clients. It doesn't sound like you need that in your app. You could still use Firebase for what you need, but frankly it sounds to me like overkill.
I think that for your simple requirements you might find Heroku easier and faster.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the app only needs a simple db to store the images and geolocation with possibility to download/access the files.